# C++ boost date format

Tags: c++, date, boost, facet

I have a vector string of dates in the from "dd-mmm-yyyy" so for example 
todays date would be:

```
  std::string today("07-Sep-2010");
```

I'd like to use the date class in boost but to create a date object the 
constructor for date needs to be called as follows:

```
 date test(2010,Sep,07);
```

Is there any easy/elegant way of passing dates in the format "dd-mmm-yyyy"?
My first thought was to use substr and then cast it? But I've read that there's also
the possibility of using 'date facets'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
include "boost/date_time/gregorian/parsers.hpp"
date test = boost::gregorian::from_us_string("07-Sep-2010")
```

Comment: Thanks! Though it should be from_uk_string:  // From delimited date string where with order day-month-year eg: 25-1-2002 or 25-Jan-2003 (full month name is also accepted). date from_uk_string(std::string s);

Comment: I'm getting a number of warnings telling me: "Function call with parameters that may be unsafe" is there any way of avoiding this?

Comment: Warning is for some internal stuff in the library#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin parser for this form of date in Boost itself, check out the docs here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_objects

date_type parse_date(...)
  Parameters:
    string_type input
    string_type format 
    special_values_parser
Parse a date from the given input using the given format.

```
string inp("2005-Apr-15");
string format("%Y-%b-%d");
date d;
d = parser.parse_date(inp, 
                      format,
                      svp);
// d == 2005-Apr-15
```

with `inp` adjusted for your needs.

Comment: What does the third argument 'svp' represent. Also should the call be format_date_parser.parse_date(inp, format, svp) ??